# contenteditable add bold, italic formatting options when text selected

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an app using Ionic, and Angular.

I implemented a `contenteditable` `div` in my application expecting that when you select text that the `bold`, `italic`, and `strike` options appear natively.. however, it doesn't seem to.

The desired effect I'd want:

[image]

How do you get the "Bold", "Italic" options when you select text? Any ideas?

Do I have to build my own function for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, WhatsApp options for contenteditable text are not the defaults. I checked on gmail, twitter and other apps and they don't have bold and italic options, just CUT, COPY, PASTE, SHARE and PAST AS PLAIN TEXT, the same that I got when I try it on my Ionic applications. Also I checked on the Ionic documentation and I didn't find anything helpful for that. So I think that you will have to build your own function for this.